# Give permission to read view but deny permissions to other tables

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

I'm new to mysql and i'm trying to create a user that only could read views so when the user get he odbc using access only can use the views and not the tables.

My problem is in mysql workbench i have to give select permissions to read the views but if i do that the user can also read the tables.

I remove user select permission and added in the editor but still cannot read that view.

```
GRANT SELECT ON Schema.view TO 'user'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'user'
```

Can you give me some advice to solve my problem please?

Comment: Will this help: https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/86802/grant-permissions-on-views-deny-select-on-tables This caught my attention: "You will have to treat the view as a table."

Answer (score 0):

The error was because in mysql workbench I was using % as localhost,

GRANT SELECT ON `database`.`view` TO 'user'@'%' identified by 'user8'

the syntax is correct, just be sure you are writting the correct localhost is this happens to you.

Thank you.